# AntiForgeryToken is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, antiforgerytoken

I've upgraded our MVC code from version 2.0 to 4.0.
And now, I'm getting the following error:
"A required Anti-Forgery Token was not supplied or was invalid."

I'm adding the below code in ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        string httpMethodOverride = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetHttpMethodOverride();
        if (!this.verbs.Verbs.Contains(httpMethodOverride, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        AntiForgeryDataSerializer antiForgeryDataSerializer = new AntiForgeryDataSerializer();
        AntiForgeryData antiForgeryData = new AntiForgeryData();
        string fieldName = antiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(null);
        string cookieName = antiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);


        HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if (cookie == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
        {
            throw CreateValidationException();
        }

        AntiForgeryData cookieToken = antiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(cookie.Value);
        //Rest of the code here//
        }
```

In "filterContext", the cookie name is "_RequestVerificationToken" and then I add the path name. The path name is encoded in Base64 and added to the AntiForgeryFieldName and this becomes "_RequestVerificationToken_Lw__".
When we check if the cookie exists, then obviously we can't find it and we get the AntiForgery exception.
But in the old version of this code, the Cookie value in "filterContext" comes as "_RequestVerificationToken_Lw__" and hence, works fine.
So, where's the issue here? Is it something related to Machine Keys or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're doing here. Anti-forgery is built in to MVC. You don't need your own attribute; just use the built-in `ValidationAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your controller action and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.AntiForgeryToken() invocation in the view generates a new token and writes in the form like this:

```
 <form action="..." method="post">        
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"        
        value="J56khgCvbE3bVcsCSZkNVuH9Cclm9SSIT/ywruFsXEgmV8CL2eW5C/gGsQUf/YuP" /> 
        <!-- Other fields. -->     
 </form>
```

and also writes it into the cookie:

```
 __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__= 
    J56khgCvbE3bVcsCSZkNVuH9Cclm9SSIT/ywruFsXEgmV8CL2eW5C/gGsQUf/YuP
```

When the above form is submitted, they are both sent to server.

In the server side, [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute is used to specify the controllers or actions to validate them:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Action(/* ... */)
{
    // ...
}
```

All you need to do is to invoke the AntiForgeryToken in the view and specify "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" attribute on the controller action.

Comment: Thank for the reply.                                                                                         Yes, we have the @html.AntiForgeryToken() in View and we have used [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute in the controller and That's how it lands in the "OnAuthorization" method that I have provided in the question. The big problem that we've been facing is that the  "_RequestVerification_Lw__" cookie does not generate for us in MVC 4.0. HttpContext.Request.Cookies has only "_RequestVerificationToken" as the cookie name and a corresponding encoded value in it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When I view source only "__RequestVerificationToken" is generated. You can try adding this line of code to validate only with "__RequestVerificationToken" instead of throwing "CreateValidationException" if the cookie is not found. Let me know if it works!

AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);

Comment: This change throws the following error:                                                     Server Error in '/' Application.

The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Comment: Could you please post your html and action signature?